# I am trying to echo an expect script into a file but no success

Tags: bash, echo, expect

I am trying to echo an expect script into a file so I can execute it on the fly.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo '#!/usr/bin/expect -f' > expect_file
echo 'expect "\[RETURN\]" {send "\r"}' >> expect_file
```

that will yield me a file with the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
"}pect "\[RETURN\]" {send "
```

If I try and use echo and escape the quotations:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo '#!/usr/bin/expect -f' > expect_file
echo "expect \"\[RETURN\]\" {send \"\r\"}" >> expect_file

cat expect_file
exit 0
```

The expect command and parts of the line do not get echoed

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
"}pect "\[RETURN\]" {send "
```

How can I echo or place the follow lines of code into a file by itself from within my bash script?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
expect "\[RETURN\]" {send "\r"}
expect ":" {send "q"}
expect "otherwise:" {send "y\r"}
expect eof {exit}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are executing the script with `bash`? That result is consistent with a POSIX-compliant implementation of `echo`, where `\r` in the argument to `echo` is treated as a literal carriage return. If you display the resulting file with `cat`, the final `"}` will appear at the beginning the line.

Comment: I came here looking for a way to `echo` out of an `expect`-script. `exec echo testbla` works, but produces no output unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use echo.  Use cat:

```
cat << 'EOF' > expect_file
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
expect "\[RETURN\]" {send "\r"}
expect ":" {send "q"}
expect "otherwise:" {send "y\r"}
expect eof {exit}
EOF
```

Comment: Right on. Worked great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Using echo**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e '#!/usr/bin/expect -f\nexpect "\\[RETURN\\]" {send "\\r"}\nexpect ":" {send "q"}\nexpect "otherwise:" {send "y\\r"}\nexpect eof {exit}' > expect_file
```

**OR**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo '#!/usr/bin/expect -f
expect "\[RETURN\]" {send "\r"}
expect ":" {send "q"}
expect "otherwise:" {send "y\r"}
expect eof {exit}' > expect_file
```

**OR**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo '#!/usr/bin/expect -f' > expect_file
echo 'expect "\[RETURN\]" {send "\r"}' >> expect_file
echo 'expect ":" {send "q"}' >> expect_file
echo 'expect "otherwise:" {send "y\r"}' >> expect_file
echo 'expect eof {exit}' >> expect_file
```

Comment: I like the second example also.